# How to consumer from a celery queue in a different app

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I have the below code in my producer application for inserting API calls into my RabbitMQ using Celery.

```
celery.send_task('tasks.process_redox', (payload,), queue="redox_inbound")
```

I was wondering, what would the code look like to consume from that queue? I have the below but it isn't working, can't seem to find it in the

```
@celery.task()
def process_redox(payload):
  data = encrypter.decrypt(payload)
  print data
  return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell celery to watch that queue.

```
app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('redox_inbound',    routing_key='default'),
)
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing